# MakeHuman models' teeth show through face in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, armature, makehuman

I am having trouble trying to get a MakeHuman model to be controlled through a python script in the BGE. The model either doesn't show the teeth, or the eyes, inner mouth and teeth appear over the model, as per the attached image. My game logic is simply a loop connecting the python script to run the armature movements.

[image].

Here is the code, note that I use numpy to manipulate a matrix which is imported using h5py library (this all works fine, moving the mouth bones). I think my problem lies in my settings, of which Blender has many, or my PC is unable to handle the graphics calculations... Any help would be greatly apprecitated!

```
import bge
import code  
import aud # audio
import numpy as np
import time
import h5py


cn=bge.logic.getCurrentController()
ow=cn.owner

##The default logic tic rate is 60 times per second (60Hz float number)
bge.logic.setLogicTicRate(25.0) #running at 25fsp

global PUpLipMid
global PLoLipMid
global PMouth_R
global PMouth_L
global PTongue
global Pjaw

global j
j=0


def main (cn):
    global j
    boneInit() #init bones to move armature
    if j<119:  #before dataMatrix runs out
        print ('main ', j)
        [TL, BL, J, MW]=getDataPoints(j)
        SKM = ratioFunction(TL, BL, J, MW)
        print('SKM\n', SKM)
        MovesBones(SKM)
        j+=1
    sa1() #sound


###################  boneInit  ######################## 
def boneInit():
    if not "init" in ow:
        ow["init"]=1
        cn.activate(cn.actuators["Armature"])


################  read data matrix  ##################
def getDataPoints(j):
    print ('getDataPoints ', j)
    with h5py.File('test.h5', 'r') as f:
        points = f['/Points'].value
        NumDataPoints=points.shape
        #print(NumDataPoints[0])
        colm=NumDataPoints[0]/4
        points.shape = (colm,4) # TL,BL,J,MW
        #print (points)
    TL=points[j,0] #Dist from nose to: Top Lip
    BL=points[j,1] #Bottom Lip
    J=points[j,2] #Jaw
    MW=points[j,3] #Mouth Width 
    return TL, BL, J, MW


###################  Ratio Function  ##################### 
def ratioFunction(TL, BL, J, MW):
#SKM matrix generated for PUpLipMid, PLoLipMid, Pjaw, PMouth_R, PMouth_L 
    #print('TL=',TL,'BL=',BL,'J=',J,'MW=',MW)
    SKM=np.zeros(shape=(5,3)) # SKM 5 bones [x(0),y(1),z(2)] coordnts 
    SKM[0][2] =(-0.002*TL-0.05) #PUpLipMid
    SKM[1][2] =(0.002*BL) #PLoLipMid
    SKM[2][2] =(0.0005*J) #Pjaw
    SKM[3][0] =(0.002*MW) #PMouth_R
    SKM[4][0] =(-0.002*MW) #PMouth_L
    #print(SKM)
    return SKM 


###################  Move bones  ########################    
def MovesBones(SKM):
    global PUpLipMid
    global PLoLipMid
    global Pjaw
    global PMouth_R
    global PMouth_L

    PUpLipMid=ow.channels["PUpLipMid"] #boneName=ow.channels["Bone"] #BL_ArmatureObject.channels["ChannelName"]
    PUpLipMid.location=[SKM[0][0],SKM[0][2],SKM[0][2]] #zero bone's local location 
    print("PUpLipMid: ",PUpLipMid.location) 
    PLoLipMid=ow.channels["PLoLipMid"] 
    PLoLipMid.location=[SKM[1][0],SKM[1][3],SKM[1][2]]
    print("PLoLipMid: ",PLoLipMid.location)
    Pjaw=ow.channels["PJaw"] 
    Pjaw.location=[SKM[2][0],SKM[2][4],SKM[2][2]]  
    print("Pjaw: ",Pjaw.location)   
    PMouth_R=ow.channels["PMouth_R"] 
    PMouth_R.location=[SKM[3][0],SKM[3][5],SKM[3][2]] 
    print("PMouth_R: ",PMouth_R.location)
    PMouth_L=ow.channels["PMouth_L"] 
    PMouth_L.location=[SKM[4][0],SKM[4][6],SKM[4][2]] 
    print("PMouth_L: ",PMouth_L.location)  



###################  audio  ########################
def sa1():
    global i
    sound = aud.Factory('sa1.mp3') #.file('sa1') #wav file in blender file  
    #print ("I TURNERED OFF THE SOUND @ main STEP2 sa1 Func!")
    if not 'play' in ow: #will play sound only once 
         ow['device'] = aud.device() 
         ow['device'].play(sound)
         ow['play'] = 1
    i=3
```

I have been playing around with many setting, including that one that you mentioned (thank for clarifying where the clipping planes option was). Your solution does help to an extent, but only if I cut through half the head, and even then the model is not full stable, as per the images below where I have the exact same settings but sometime the teeth and eye pop out when I run the GBE. 
[image]

Comment: What are your near and far clipping planes set to in the viewport? If the near plane is set too small, you can start to get errors that look a lot like this.

Comment: If you disable your script and run the game, does the model still have the problems?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. If I disable the script I get the same effect, yes. @Justin, I am still a noob with Blender, I have Google'd clipping planes but could not fine anything helpful. Can you be a bit more specific? I cannot find many problems of the same kind on the web, but it is common for such distortions to occur in the BGE if your graphics card or RAM cannot handle the worklooad? I have a i7, 6GB RAM PC with Gefroce GT 630m-2GB Nvidia graphics card, surely that should handle a single character mesh being manipulated in the BGE?

Comment: The graphics card ram does not cause this kind of artifacts. To me it looks like the depth test is deactivated. This will cause objects to always be drawn on  top of the previous ones. Under which circumstances are the teeth and eyes on top and when is the body on top?

Comment: @maddin45 -It seems like the teeth and eyes pop over the face randomly, but after a lot of clicking it does seem to go in a some vague cycle of showing the eyes and teeth, then no eyes and teeth, and then a mix of teeth or eyes over the face. How does one go about activating the 'depth test'?

Comment: I have not found a setting in Blender but, you can try calling opengl functions directly from python. Make sure to `import bgl` and call `bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)`. Not sure if it will work, but it is worth a shot ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't seem to do anything, in the python console and in the script (but no error came up so I am assuming it accepted the code), I think I should point out I am using Blender 2.70a. I can share the .blend file if it will help?

Comment: To change the clipping planes, put your mouse in the 3D view, hit 'N' on your keyboard and look for the 'View' options. The setting you're looking for is called 'Start' under 'Clip.' If this is set to a really small value, you *may* start to see things show up that are actually behind something closer to the camera (like teeth instead of lips).

Comment: Thanks, I added more to my original questions post in response to this. In short it didn't solve the problem, it just made it less likely to happen. But now this brings up another quick question, if my now have a floating face (which if fine for the work I need to do) how do I get the clip settings to be applied to the camera view in the Standalone Player in the BGE?

Comment: I still cannot solve this problem? I might swap to Unity...

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems, it seems to be a problem with depth sorting in blender. What helped me was setting:

Materials > Game Setting > Alpha Blend > set it to "Alpha Clip"
You should do this for the teeth and eyes, maybe skin aswell(try one at a time).

Other options that may have an effect on this problem are "Back Face Culling" and "Transparency".